# I can't disable the touchpad by using Disable-PnpDevice Powershell command

Tags: python, powershell

I'm trying to build a small app that will enable/disable the touchpad with a keyboard shortcut. So I wrote a Python script with just one function. That function is using the subprocess module to run a Disable-PnpDevice Powershell command. Then i converted that Python script to an exe file. After creating a desktop shortcut of the exe file, I assigned a keyboard shortcut to the file by right clicking and changing its properties.

I'm running this command in administrator mode:

`Disable-PnpDevice -InstanceId '<touchpad id here>'`

It doesn't give any error and when i check the device manager i can see that the touchpad is disabled. But still i am able to use touchpad. I heard that sometimes the touchpad driver can override the system settings and disabling touchpad from commands would not work because of that. Is there any way to prevent the driver from doing that? If i try to disable touchpad by using Regedit, same thing happens too. The touchpad is still working even though it's disabled on Regedit. Is there any kind of workaround?

Comment: The touchpad in a laptop is partly managed and owned by the BIOS itself.  Otherwise, you couldn't use it during boot.  There is often a Fn-key to disable the touchpad.  Do you have that?

Comment: No unfortunatley i don't have that. Actually that's why i'm trying to build a simple app like this.